# making an android activity run without ui

Tags: java, android, service

I have a startingActivity on Google-glass

I want to run it sometimes silently,

meaning it will run, communicate with the server,

get and send data - but the user won't see the app.

The user will see a static card from time to time,

but basically can be in a context of another app.

my tries:

1. I have thought to create a service instead of my
   startingActivity,but there are too many things that relays on the main UI views
2. If I comment out the setContentView(), all my code that refers
   `view.findViewById()` will fail. no? and besides the user will see a
   black screen instead of silent run which i desire.
3. any other solution for silent run, but yet running the
   startingActivity fully?

Comment: you have views but you don't want to display it?

Comment: yes, but i also want the whole app to run in the background. not seeing black screen. and i guess not inflating the xml (setContentView) will fail my code in many places.

Comment: set visiblity of all widgets to false in that xml.

Comment: i would go with option 1: but still with option 2 you can use Transllucent theme

Comment: @pskink but sometimes i want the activity to be seen. not always transparent. anyhow your solution will make the user see black screen no?

Comment: @pskink can I set activity theme via code on run time?

Comment: why at runrime? set it to translucent, no black screens, just your views, or nothing if you setVisibility of your root view to GONE

Comment: @pskink because depending on the launch trigger i sometimes want to make the root view visible

Comment: ok create activity with translucent rheme and setContentView with a TextView wirh params wrap_content/wrap_content and see what happens

Comment: how would that show my starting activity when needed to be seen?\